# How to append second row data to first row in apache nifi flow file

Tags: apache-nifi

I want to use some group by or append my all rows data  to first row in my apache file, my scenario goes like below
I have a flow file which has csv data with tab as a separator, like below

```
1   101 AAA
2   101 BBB
3   101 CCC
```

so here second column(101) is common in all my rows, now i want my output be like below

```
101,AAA BBB CCC
```

I have used ExtractText with the regex `([^\t]*)\n$`  but in my flowfile i can see the attribute only the last row that is 3,101,CCC. Could anyone please help me out here

Answer (score 1):

Use a `QueryRecord` processor:

- `Record Reader`: `CSVReader`

  - `CSV Format`: `Tab-Delimited`
- `Record Writer`: `CSVRecordSetWriter`

  - `Include Header Line`: `false`
- `aggr` (dynamic property):

```sql
SELECT code, LISTAGG(name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY name) AS list
FROM FLOWFILE
GROUP BY code
```

**Example**

**input** (with header)

```
number  code    name
1   101 AAA
2   101 BBB
3   101 CCC
```

**output**

```
101,"AAA,BBB,CCC"
```